# Binary tree searching with strings

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

This is my code so far to find all of the nodes represented by char characters. I've been able to code how to get the root node's "(" and ")" using the helper method. However, i'm having a mind block when trying to integrate the helper method into the treeProcessor. In the treeProcessor method i'm trying to further delve into binary tree so that the end goal is to just print out the root node and sub trees.

```
public static ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String tree = "(a(b()())(c()()))";

        //replace this line with a call to the treeProcessor
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(treeBreakdownHelper(tree)));//a, (b()()), (c()())
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(paths);//prints every path found
    }

    //recursive method
    public static void treeProcessor(String tree, String path)
    {
        //breakdown tree


        //update path


        //check if current element is leaf/last element
            //if it is, add to ArrayList

        //if not last element, run processor again on subtrees that are not empty
    }
    //valid tree:
    //(a()())
    //(a(b()())(c()()))
    //helper method
    public static String[] treeBreakdownHelper(String tree)
    {
        String[] temp = new String[3];
        //0 = root
        //1 = left tree
        //2 = right tree
        tree = tree.substring(1, tree.length()-1);

        //System.out.println(tree);//test removal of outer parens
        temp[0] = "" + tree.charAt(0);
        tree = tree.substring(1);

        //System.out.println(tree);//test removal of root node
        int openCount = 0;
        int middle = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < tree.length(); i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(openCount);
            if(tree.charAt(i) == '(')
            {
                openCount++;
            }
            else if(tree.charAt(i) == ')')
            {
                openCount--;
            }
            if(openCount == 0)
            {
                middle = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(middle);
        //System.out.println(tree.substring(0,middle+1));
        temp[1] = tree.substring(0,middle+1);
        //System.out.println(tree.substring(middle+1));
        temp[2] = tree.substring(middle+1);

        return temp;

    }

}
```

Comment: Internet is overflowing with samples.  Have you looked at them yet?

Comment: Looks like a somewhat disguised "write my code for me" attempt.